# mysql + PHP voting system with ranking

Tags: php, mysql

This is the current system. When a user votes on an item his IP and the POST_ID are recorded into the IP_LOG table. The problem is I wish to order posts by their rank (Upvotes-Downvotes).

So the display is something like .

1. POST_ID -> 32425 (7 upvotes)
2. POST_ID -> 12331 (4 upvotes)
3. POST_ID -> 24211 (3 upvotes)

This is simple enough the problem becomes when an item in the list moves up or down, **I wish to allow any user who voted on this item to be able to re-vote on that item.**

So if item 3 were to receive 2 up-votes it would switch place with item 2, then I would remove from the IP log table all IP's that voted for either 12331 or 24211.

1. POST_ID -> 32425 (7 upvotes)
2. POST_ID -> 24211 (5 upvotes)
3. POST_ID -> 12331 (4 upvotes)

Table **IP_LOG**

```
ID  |     IP          | POST_ID | 
---------------------------------
1   |  xxx.xxx.xx     |  12331  |  
---------------------------------
2   |  yyy.yyy.yy     |  12331  |
```

Table **POST_RANK**

```
ID  | POST_ID | Downvotes | Upvotes
-----------------------------------
1   |  32425  |  3        |  10
-----------------------------------
2   |  12331  |  1        |  5
-----------------------------------
3   |  24211  |  1        |  4
```

My question is this:

**What would be my SQL query that allows me to select the rank of the POST_ID based on the amount of (upvotes-downvotes)**

something that returns :

1. POST_ID => 32425,  Rank => 1
2. POST_ID => 12331,  Rank => 2
3. POST_ID => 24211,  Rank => 3

attempt :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM POST_RANK
         WHERE Upvotes - Downvotes) AS Rank
```

Alternatively what would be another way to accomplish this functionality without using a cron job. I want it updated immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT (Upvotes - Downvotes) as Rank
          FROM POST_RANK
         WHERE post_id=<id>
```

Update:

Try this:

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rank, p.* FROM POST_RANK, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r order by (Upvotes - Downvotes) desc
```

Comment: this always returns the same rank unfortunately

Comment: @Undermine2k the same rank for the same `post_id` yes.

Comment: I need it to recalculate the rank based on the # of up-votes an item currently has this doesn't do that.

Comment: hey this works but anyway i could limit it by an ID as to say where post_id = $id, because if I do that it returns rank 1 for everything